# How to compute Kerr geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, computational-physics, geodesics, kerr-metric

How would I start to numerically compute trajectories of Kerr geodesics with constants of motion like in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Trajectory_equations). I want to recreate trajectories like in this picture in Matlab.
[image]

Comment: It's better to use Mathematica where packages are already available for computing things like these.

Comment: @Avantgarde thx for your reply. I don't want to use mathematica at first. I startet to implement the ode in Matlab and solved it with standard ode-solver. I'm curious to know how the constant of motions and intial conditions are set up.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: MATLAB does not seem to have any built-in support for GR. So possibly the best way is first to obtain the system of equations from another system that does have GR support and export it to MATLAB. For example [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sagemanifolds/SageManifolds/blob/master/Worksheets/v1.3/SM_Schwarzschild_geod.ipynb) is SageManifolds notebook for geodesics in Schwarzschild metric, An ODE system ready to export is after the line `sys = geod.system(verbose=True)`.

Comment: @Qmechanic it is already there: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32765/20688

Comment: The equations of motion in the Wikipedia article you have linked do not work on the radial and poloidial turning points, use the ones from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_around_a_rotating_Kerr_black_hole.gif#Equations_of_motion instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seminal paper on Kerr Geodesics is [Wilkins](http://www.icra.it/Publications/Scientific/files/LenseThirring/pdf/b_Wilkins.pdf).  The necessary equations are found at 2 and 3.

Note that it is *not trivial* to implement these equations by plugging into an RK4 integrator because of the square roots in the R and Theta "potential" functions.

Comment: why recommed the equations with a ± in front of the radial and poloidial derivatives, there are much better equations for numerical integration, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02063.pdf#page=3

Comment: Heh, I wasn't aware of that one, it is a bit more recent, cheers! (reading)

Comment: @Yukterez I really don't know why I didn't mention my own method in my answer, must have been a bit shy at the time . . or just answering the question?  I square the Wilkins equations, then use a symplectic integrator to evolve a "pseudo hamiltonian" in Mino time.  https://github.com/m4r35n357/ODE-Playground  Incidentally, there are now explicit solutions for the Wilkins equations in Mino time. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.05090